# Pandas, how to reindex a dataframe that is generated from appending multiple dataframe.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is generated from appending multiple dataframe together into a long list. As shown in figure, the default index is a loop between 0 ~ 7 because each original df has this index. The total row number is 240. So how can reindex the new df into 0~239 instead of 30 x 0~7.

I tried `df.reset_index(drop=True)`, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried:`df.reindex(np.arange(240))` but it returned error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you forget assign output, because by default [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) does not work `inplace`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

But better solution is (if use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)) add parameter `ignore_index=True`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, ..., df7], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your `append()` method to ignore index:

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```